# Tag totals should include synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms

Due to synonyms the number of posts for a tag isn't fully representative of its popularity.

For instance when you [view all tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) debugging(4278) has the synonym debug(876).  This totals more than 5k which means debugging should be on the first page,  but it is currently on the 2nd page.

Comment: Do you mean those tags should be combined into `debugging` and `debug` marked as a synonym for it? Why have two tags if you're trying to count them as one?

Comment: @GMan The "debug" tag is already a synonym of "debugging", but it hasn't been merged yet so there are still 876 questions with that tag. Until it does, it keeps its own separate post count. The proposal here is to link their post counts even while they are still hosted under separate tags.

Comment: @Grace Note yes, that is my suggestion.

Comment: @Grace: Ah, okay. This is just a band-aid, then? Shouldn't we fix the actual problem by merging them?

Comment: Im sorry Rook, I'm declining this due to Bills answer, we have been slack merging tags, that is the real problem that needs to be addressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this requires a code change, but a tag clean up.  I merged the example you gave and will start looking at others that have synonyms but aren't merged.

I don't think a code change is really called for because this should only be a problem on original trilogy sites, particularly SO.  If other site moderators stay on top of their tags and synonyms from the beginning, things won't get out of control they way they did on SO.

Comment: If this problem requires human intervention then it will continue to be a systemic issue across all sites.

Comment: @Rook: The real problem is that the tags aren't merged, which requires human intervention anyway.  What order tags appear on the list is really secondary.

Comment: .. there are **3** pages of cleanup which are overdue :)  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=merge Ill go through a few now, but help would be much appreciated

Comment: @waffles: I merged about 50 of them but that is some really boring work.  I'll keep at it though.  Thanks for lending a hand.  :)  (Also, thanks for adding that "merge" link to the synonyms UI.  It would take 5X as long to merge tags without it.)

Comment: @waffles thank you for providing anecdotal evidence to support my argument.

Comment: Now if only there was some help text describing the "merge" tab @waffles made; the most appropriate page that I could find is http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms but that doesn't do much more than mention the existence of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms :-(