# Drop -api/-sdk in tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

[facebook-api] and [iphone-sdk] were [recently renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68183/are-these-really-the-tag-synonyms-we-want):

> Keeping in mind that SO is solely a programming site, the -api in [facebook-api] seems redundant and a needless split.  Surely [facebook] is just as useful, and splitting these questions into [foo] and [foo-api] just makes it harder to search.  There are questions involving Facebook that don't use the API, but not all of them should be tagged [facebook] in the first place.  ...  However, using the non-api tag supports tagging that kind of question (by lumping it in with the APIs), while still being a net gain in usefulness.

Could several other -api and -sdk tags be merged?  Treat this list as a rough draft. There are a few more -api/-sdk tags where I'm less inclined to suggest renaming just yet.

- [[facebook-graph]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-graph/synonyms) ← [[facebook-graph-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-graph-api)
- [[flickr]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flickr/synonyms) ← [[flickr-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flickr-api)
- [[gdata]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gdata/synonyms) ← [[gdata-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gdata-api)
- [[google-adwords]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-adwords/synonyms) ← [[google-adwords-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-adwords-api)
- [[google-analytics]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-analytics/synonyms) ← [[google-analytics-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-analytics-api)
- [[google-calendar]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-calendar/synonyms) ← [[google-calendar-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-calendar-api)
- [[google-data]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-data/synonyms) ← [[google-data-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-data-api)
- [[google-docs]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-docs/synonyms) ← [[google-docs-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-docs-api)
- [[google-search]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-search/synonyms) ← [[google-search-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-search-api)
- [[google]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google/synonyms) ← [[google-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-api)
- [[paypal]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/paypal/synonyms) ← [[paypal-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/paypal-api)
- [[sound]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sound/synonyms) ← [[sound-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sound-api)
- [[twitter]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter/synonyms) ← [[twitter-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter-api)
- [[youtube]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/youtube/synonyms) ← [[youtube-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/youtube-api)

- [[android]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms) ← [[android-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-sdk)
- [[facebook]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/synonyms) ← [[facebook-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-sdk)
- [[flex]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flex/synonyms) ← [[flex-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flex-sdk)
- [[ipad]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ipad/synonyms) ← [[ipad-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ipad-sdk)
- [[itunes]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itunes/synonyms) ← [[itunes-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itunes-sdk)
- [[mojo]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mojo/synonyms) ← [[mojo-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mojo-sdk)
- [[openxml]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/openxml/synonyms) ← [[openxml-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/openxml-sdk)
- [[powershell]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/synonyms) ← [[powershell-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell-sdk)
- [[tfs]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tfs/synonyms) ← [[tfs-sdk]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tfs-sdk)

Answer (score 7):

Well, keep in mind that some libraries are actually *named* "... SDK" or "... API". Windows has the Plaform SDK, which you might use to target the Windows API. Those aren't just descriptions - they're the *official names*.

I would be especially leery about stripping the "sdk" part from "visual-studio-sdk" - those are questions specific to developing software that runs within that application, vs. the many [visual-studio] questions that are merely about *using* the application.

I'm sure there are tags where a -sdk or -api suffix is more than a bit silly, but please be reluctant to engage in damning by pattern-matching...

Comment: I left [windows-sdk] and [platform-sdk] out for exactly that reason (though I'm undecided), but I'm not familiar with everything listed.  I want to get people to look at this, which is why it's a rough draft.

Comment: +1: Visual Studio SDK is developing *for* Visual Studio extensions/integration, this is a different thing to a question about developing something *in* Visual Studio.

Comment: s/prefix/suffix/g