# What should be done with the Gosu tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Apparently, it's both a [2D game development library](http://code.google.com/p/gosu/) and a [new programming language](http://gosu-lang.org/). Should the official tag for the programming language be gosu-lang? Should the existing tag for the library be renamed to gosu-lib?

Comment: Any idea which is more mainstream?

Comment: Following the example of [flex](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags) we should preemptively retag questions about the earlier product with a incorrect alternate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The home for the library is http://libgosu.org/ while the language is at http://gosu-lang.org/.

Why not use [libgosu](/questions/tagged/libgosu) for the library and [gosu-lang](/questions/tagged/gosu-lang) for the language, then anything tagged [gosu](/questions/tagged/gosu) can stick out like a sore thumb to be retagged.  Both tags would be suggested by entering "gosu" in the tags field, and it *should* be obvious to the user which is appropriate.

It still might make sense to synonym [gosu](/questions/tagged/gosu) with the more popular use, which looks to be the library — except there's only 5 library questions vs 2 language questions and it's definitely not a problem yet.

Comment: To compare, we [recently resolved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68185) a similar ambiguity problem with both [link] and [linking]: hyperlink vs linking object files (e.g. in C).